# Change height of element UI table rows

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I want to decrease the spacing of the Element UI table rows to fit more rows on the screen.

Unfortunately I can't see any option in the Element UI docs:
https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table

Setting directly a definied height for the class `el-table__row` didn't result in any change of height.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use one of the following methods:

1) set the `size` attribute with "small" or "mini"

```
<el-table :data="tableData" size="small">
```

2) use the `cell-style` attribute to remove padding from cells and set a fixed height

```
<el-table :data="tableData" :cell-style="{padding: '0', height: '20px'}">
```

Here's the complete list of the available options: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table-attributes

Comment: It went with `:cell-style="{padding: '3px', height: '20px'}"`